# Does anyone comment on why Yonah needed the kikayon when he already had shade from his sukkah?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, yonah-jonah-book-of

In [Yonah 4](https://www.sefaria.org/Jonah.4.5?lang=bi&with=Sheets&lang2=en) verse 5 says:

> וַיֵּצֵ֤א יוֹנָה֙ מִן־הָעִ֔יר וַיֵּ֖שֶׁב מִקֶּ֣דֶם לָעִ֑יר וַיַּעַשׂ֩
>   ל֨וֹ שָׁ֜ם סֻכָּ֗ה וַיֵּ֤שֶׁב תַּחְתֶּ֙יהָ֙ בַּצֵּ֔ל עַ֚ד אֲשֶׁ֣ר
>   יִרְאֶ֔ה מַה־יִּהְיֶ֖ה בָּעִֽיר׃
>
> Now Jonah had left the city and found a place east of the city. He
>   made a booth there and sat under it in the shade, until he should see
>   what happened to the city.

So Yonah had shade in his Sukkah. Verse 6 says:

> וַיְמַ֣ן יְהוָֽה־אֱ֠לֹהִים קִיקָי֞וֹן וַיַּ֣עַל ׀ מֵעַ֣ל לְיוֹנָ֗ה
>   לִֽהְי֥וֹת צֵל֙ עַל־רֹאשׁ֔וֹ לְהַצִּ֥יל ל֖וֹ מֵרָֽעָת֑וֹ וַיִּשְׂמַ֥ח
>   יוֹנָ֛ה עַל־הַקִּֽיקָי֖וֹן שִׂמְחָ֥ה גְדוֹלָֽה׃
>
> The LORD God provided a kikayon , which grew up over Jonah, to provide
>   shade for his head and save him from discomfort. Jonah was very happy
>   about the plant.

There seems to be a clear question, “If he had a sukkah with shade, why did he need a kikayon?” and a simple answer - “The kikayon gave valuable extra shade.”

Is there any commentator who asks the question? I am not satisfied with the simple answer.

Comment: I do not see the two verses as chronological. Insert the word "because" or "for" between verse 5 and 6 and then read it again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Radak says:

ואף על פי שעשה לו סוכה לצל, אולי יבשו עצי הסוכה, כי ישב שם עד מלאות לו ארבעים יום.

And Mezudat David:

כי צל הסוכה הוא דבר שאינו מתמיד, כי הולך ומתייבש מחום השמש; ולא כן הקיקיון, היונק רטיבות הארץ.

Both explain the fronds Yonah put up dried out (Since he apperantly waited there  for some time), and he then needed​ another solution.

Comment: Odd though that he couldn't just go pick some fresh fronds.